# Angular - Where to store permanent user information except on local storage

Tags: angular, security, jwt

I a  system where the authentication is made via JWT, on the local storage the JWT is set on a variable and the user roles in another variable on the local storage. However, all the information ( including the JWT ) is encrypted via CryptoJS, and then on the side bar, for example, we have ngIfs for showing some menus only for users with certain roles. All these ngIfs call a method that decrypt the data on the local storage to get the user roles, then it does the validation. The problem is that all these decryptions in multiple icons/sidebar icons/etc are starting to make the system REALLY slow.
So does anybody have an idea to where to save user data in this case? :)

Comment: Why don't you store the decrypted data in the local storage in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a:

**[Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)**: a shared service ( declare it in your root module ) that can be accessed from any components, make sure to decrypt the information at first and store it inside a variable inside your service.

**[Store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store)**: Something like Redux where you can store the decrypted user information, and access it from anywhere.

Comment: No, but if you want to not lose data when refreshing, you can load data from your local storage to your service when refreshing at the application start only.

Comment: Yeah i tried that, on user service constructor i am checking local storage for the token, then storing the information in the user service when it's there. I got interrupted while doing it today, but i will do it later and i will come back here to tell if it worked, thanks anyway man

Comment: Cool, make sure you add your code to the question if something doesn't work.

Comment: yup, worked like a charm. The only thing i have to worry is to make the service provided in root right ? In this case the user service is declared in app.module so it will always refresh the variable when i refresh the page correct? Also the providedIn: 'root' decorator would work in this case?

Comment: Yes the service will be recreated each time you refresh the page, but the decryption will be excuted only at the refresh, and yes the service providedIn is 'root' wich means a singleton service, and that's what you need, only one instance of your wich is shared between components.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule I use is to ever use functions on things like `*ngIf` where they are processed every digest cycle. That is why your performance is taking a hit. Try putting a `console.log()` in the decrypt function and see how many times it is called per second.

You can store the encrypted value in local storage, and then use a service to store the decrypted value in memory. Then you call the service to get the decrypted value. Then if a user refreshes the page they have to decrypt it again once and then pass around the decrypted value. Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

**service.ts**

```
decryptedValue = null;

getDecryptedValue() {
    if (!decryptedValue) {
        this.decryptedValue = this.decrypt(localStorage.getItem('encryptedValueKey'));
    }
    return this.decryptedValue;
}
```

**component.ts**

```
temp = null;

ngOnInit() {
    this.temp = this.service.getDecryptedValue();
}
```

Then you can call the service from any component you want and it should be fairly fast compared to what you're doing now